# Appium failed to create session

Tags: android, android-emulator, appium

I am following this Appium tutorial: https://youtu.be/i1tQ1pjEFWw and my Appium failed to start a session. This is the error I'm getting from the inspector:

Failed to create session. The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource

This is the JSON representation I am using:

```
{
  "appium:deviceName": "emulator-5554",
  "platformName": "android",
  "appium:appPackage": "com.android.calculator2",
  "appium:appActivity": ".Calculator",
  "appium:noReset": true
}
```

This is the error shown on Appium:

```
[HTTP] No route found for /session
[HTTP] <-- POST /session 404 14 ms - 211
```

My emulator is working fine and it shows on adb devices. I am using a Pixel 2 API 28 emulator from Android Studio.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15lXY.png)

Answer (score 7):

[Important migration information from Appiun-Inspector](https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector#important-migration-notes)

**Important migration notes**

This version of Appium Inspector is designed to work with Appium 2.0 as a default. So if you are migrating from Appium Desktop (which is designed to work with Appium 1.x as a default), you need to be aware of some changes:

The default remote server path has changed from /wd/hub to / to reflect Appium 2.0's default server path. If you're using Appium Inspector with an Appium 1.x server, you'll likely need to update the path information in the New Session form back to /wd/hub.

Answer (score 4):

My problem solved with this :

1-In your device -> Settings -> Apps then search uiautomator , 2 apps will pop up .

2-Uninstall them.

This error occurs when the session crash several times.

**Pay attention : first of all check the server address in your code with appium server name.**

Answer (score 3):

I was using Appium v1.22.2 and faced same issue.

I had to set Remote path  as /wd/hub and it worked

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31191606)

Comment: Where can I set the remote path in the project?

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall and Reinstall the app on device works for me (with Appium 1.22.2)